# How data stores in Azure Search SDK

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

Can anybody tell me about how Azure Search SDK Store and Manipulate data (with out using the Azure SQL) whether it have any other data storing technique other than SQL ,

and how the searching criteria works?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of sample code on the Azure site for using Azure Search, including this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-dotnet-sdk/

Here is another good article to get you started: http://fabriccontroller.net/introducing-microsoft-azure-search-and-the-reddog-search-client-sdk/

Neither samples are specific to Azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Azure Search does not store data in a relational way (like SQL), it stores Json-like objects.

Azure Search provides an API to add/remove/lookup/search indexes, the SDK simplifies the API usage but wrapping everything in simple classes and methods, like dgiard mentioned in the first link.

Once an item has been added, it will be indexed according to the Index definition (those fields marked as Searchable will be Analized, the Facetable fields will be processed, etc.).

To answer your second question, by default, Azure Search will evaluate your search query over the Searchable fields using a [TF-IDF](http://www.tfidf.com/) algorithm that defines a score for each item, ordering the results by this score. You can always [create your Custom Scoring Profiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798928.aspx) if you want to apply custom logic to this score.

Hope this helps!